# JS: how can i use a generated random number and set it to background color of a div

Tags: javascript, css

I have a "var rgb" that generates a RGB color for each click in a div. Now i want to randomly apply it as background color to one of the div's inside "#game". How can i do it?

index.html

```
<header>
  <p class="great">xxx</p>
  <p id="rgb">RGB(143, 80, 16)</p>
  <p class="great">xxxx</p>
</header>

<nav>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="newColors">NEW COLORS</div>
    <div id="result">RESULT</div>
    <div id="easy"><span>EASY</span> <span>HARD</span></div>
  </div>
</nav>


  <div id="game">
    <div class="firstSquare"></div>
    <div class="secondSquare"></div>
    <div class="thirdquare"></div>



    <div class="firstSquare"></div>
    <div class="secondSquare"></div>
    <div class="thirdquare"></div>
  </div>
```

script.js

```
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var rgb = "RGB(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";

  var colorRGB = document.getElementById("rgb");
  var headerRGB = document.getElementById("newColors");
  var squareOne = document.getElementById("one");

  headerRGB.addEventListener("click", function() {
     colorRGB.textContent = rgb;
     squareOne.style.backgroundColor = "rgb";
  });
```

Comment: `el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0,0,0)';`

Comment: you have rgb in quotes, also why are you setting text color to be the same as bg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rgb` is a variable, not a string. You accidentally put it in quotes. Try:

```
squareOne.style.backgroundColor = rgb
```

Also, if you want to generate a new random color on each click, put your randomization logic inside the event listener:

```
 var colorRGB = document.getElementById("rgb")
 var headerRGB = document.getElementById("newColors")
 var game = document.getElementById("game")

 headerRGB.addEventListener("click", function() {
   var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
   var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
   var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
   var rgb = "RGB(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")"

   colorRGB.textContent = rgb
   var div = game.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * game.children.length)]
   div.style.backgroundColor = rgb
 })
```

Comment: don't know why i did the quotes :). Anyway, the point is to apply the color to random div also. Each div is a square, and i wan't to have each time a different square with that color

Comment: I just edited the post to do that. Note that you need to remove the duplicate id of `game` from your nav element for this to work.

Comment: @fields Did the changes I made do what you requested?